# Django - Positive/Negative Integerfield depending on choice

Tags: python, django, model

I have a model which consists of cashflows: positive and negative ones. I would like to enforce a positive or negative amount when a user fills in a form.

So basically:

> 1. first you choose inflow or outflow
> 2. next you type in the amount. the sign will depend on your previous choice

How can I achieve this? I am aware of PositiveIntegerField which works such as Integerfield but don't see how to integrate this in the model?

```
class CashFlow(models.Model):

 POSITIVE= 'inflow'
 NEGATIVE= 'outflow'

cashflowchoices = (
    (POSITIVE, 'inflow'),
    (NEGATIVE, 'outflow'),
    )

type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices = cashflowchoices, default=CALL)
amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default='1')
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want to achieve. Surely you can just get the user to put in the absolute value and set the sign in the type field; you don't need to change anything in the form.

Comment: hi Daniel. How can I set the sign in the type filed? Which attribute? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can override the modal save method for the same

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.type == 'outflow':
         if self.amount > 0:
             self.amount = self.amount * -1
    else:
         if self.amount < 0:
             self.amount = self.amount * -1
    super(CashFlow, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```